# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting a console error:

```js
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined".
```

I am using `jQuery Datatable`.

Comment: Show you code here htm and jquery ?

Comment: See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: Cannot set property ‘nTf’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-set-property-ntf-of-undefined) for more information.

Answer (score 70):

Okey Let me just to be clear for everyone, **`tfoot > th`** must be equal to your **`thead > th`**

I just faced this kind of problem recently and trying to figure it out for couple mins so just make sure in the future someone maybe is facing it

Answer (score 35):

As per https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22697/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-ntf-of-undefined you probably have more cells in the header and/or footer of your table defined in your html than you are getting back from the server.

At least that's the issue I was having which gave me this error message.

Comment: How did you fix this? I am not using a footer at all but getting the same error message.

Comment: I fixed it by returning as many columns from the server as there are cells in the header in the HTML :).

Answer (score 18):

Hi I had same problem but now I have fixed my problem. This problem occurs because there are more column in head tag than body tag. If you have same error then first check how many column in thead and tbody or tfoot .

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I had empty tfoot which was causing error. Simply removed tfoot as is not required in my case and it is working fine.

Answer (score 11):

Also, this error occurred for me when the columns in my Datatables setup did not match the columns in my HTML.

I fixed it by making sure they match.

(In the image below, they do not match, which caused the error.)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The number of `<th>` in the header and footer section should match

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Subject Areas</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Option(s)</th>
    <tr>
</thead>

<tbody></tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your table Check all colspan attribute values if its equal to the number of columns

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too. All columns in tfoot matched thead. Just a simple step of clearing browser cache did the magic for me. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause involve functions which reference non-existent column indices.  For example, I only had 8 columns but this function referenced column index 10 which caused the error.

```
...
initComplete: function () {
   this.api().columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 10]).every(function () {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of `<th>` in the header and footer section should match or you can use `colspan`

```
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>{{__("ID")}}</th>
           <th>{{__("Ar Name")}}</th>
           <th>{{__("En Name")}}</th>
           <th width="70">{{__("Control")}}</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
        <tr>
           <th colspan="4"></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the server side processing method.
I was able to resolve mine by ensuring that the columns property in the datatable options is the same as the table thead and table tfoot columns.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem twice,
first time solved by adding the missing tag (must be equal on both sides)
The second time solved it by refreshing the cache of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

And if you have 'columns' option, check quantity

```
columns: [
    { className: "select-filter" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```