# jQuery Datatables Uncaught TypeError Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having the following error with the jQuery DataTables plugin. I am having the same amount of data, TDs in header and footer, and set columns in JS.

If I remove the last column (action) it works fine. But I need that to handle the action for the row.

> I am using it in WordPress with AJAX

### Javascript

```
$('#gsAllOrdersTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: ajax_vars.ajax_url + '?action=gs_carts_datatable_server'
    },
    columns: [
        {data: 'updated_date'},
        {data: 'group'},
        {data: 'username'},
        {data: 'number_of_products'},
        {data: 'total_sales_amount'},
        {data: 'order_number'},
        {data: 'status'},
        {data: 'action', searchable: false},
    ],
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.className = 'form-control';
            $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                });
        });
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<table id="gsAllOrdersTable"
       class="gs-orders-table gs-table table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php _e('Updated Date', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Group', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Username', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Number of Products', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Total Sales Amount', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Order Number', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Status', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Action', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orders-data-rows" class="gs-orders-data"></tbody>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><?php _e('Updated Date', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Group', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Username', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Number of Products', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Total Sales Amount', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Order Number', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Status', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
        <th><?php _e('Action', 'my-plugin') ?></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

### PHP

```
public function get_user_active_cart_list_jason()
{
    $json_data = [];

    // get cart data
    $cart_dara = $this->get_user_active_cart(get_current_user_id(), gs_get_user_group());

    // return empty json if no data
    if (empty($cart_dara)) {
        return json_encode(['data' => $json_data]);
    }

    //prepare data for json
    $json_data[] = [
        'updated_date'       => $cart_dara[ 'common' ][ 'cart_updated_date' ],
        'group'              => $cart_dara[ 'common' ][ 'group_name' ],
        'username'           => $cart_dara[ 'common' ][ 'group_user' ],
        'number_of_products' => $cart_dara[ 'total' ][ 'item_count' ],
        'total_sales_amount' => $cart_dara[ 'total' ][ 'cart_total_formatted' ],
        'order_number'       => $cart_dara[ 'common' ][ 'order_number' ],
        'status'             => __('Open', 'group-shop'),
        'action'             => '<button type="button" onclick="alert(1)">Click Me!</button>',
    ];

    return json_encode(['data' => $json_data]);
}
```

### Generated HTML

```
<table id="gsAllOrdersTable"
       class="gs-orders-table gs-table table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Updated Date</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Number of Products</th>
        <th>Total Sales Amount</th>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orders-data-rows" class="gs-orders-data"></tbody>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Updated Date</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Number of Products</th>
        <th>Total Sales Amount</th>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?  Do the columns in your datatables match the columns in my HTML?  Does this help solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481601/3825777

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS I have added generated HTML code to the question. Although no different than the source.